# Docker-compose cannot start mysql, permission denied to /tmp

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to start a docker container from the vanilla `mariadb` image from docker hub using docker-compose. While everything previously worked, I'm now getting the error message `Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibLTxiq7' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")`. Here's the full log:

```
139707238336448 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.14-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 51 ...
139707238336448 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
139707238336448 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
139707238336448 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
139707238336448 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
139707238336448 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
139707238336448 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
139707238336448 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
139707238336448 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/ibLTxiq7' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
7f10205047c0  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
139707238336448 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
139707238336448 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
139707238336448 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
139707238336448 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I don't understand, does the `/tmp` folder in the log refer to the host machine or the container? How would I fix this issue?

The command I'm trying to run (as root user) is `docker-compose up db`. I've checked that there indeed is space on the disk. My OS Ubuntu 16.04.

**Update: My `docker-compose.yml-file`**

```yaml
https-portal:
  image: steveltn/https-portal
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
  links:
    - wordpress
  restart: always
  environment:
    DOMAINS: 'domain.com -> http://wordpress'
    STAGE: 'production'
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - db:mysql
  volumes:
    - ~/wordpress/wp_html:/var/www/html
db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: [---]
```

**Update 2:**

I seem to have (at least temporarily) solved the problem, rather surprisingly, by adding a volume mount path for the db container:

```yaml
db:
  image: mariadb
  volumes:
    - /data/maridb:/var/lib/mysql
```

**However** this does not actually affect anything, it just prints a warning that the volume mount *is not used* (and indeed it isn't) because the container has previously been created with a different volume and the old one is used. **Still**, the original problem disappears. Any thoughts on what causes this behavior?

Comment: docker command you're trying to run would be helpful, also make sure you have some space on your disk to run new containers

Comment: What docker commands are you running? Any security in play here (SELinux / AppArmor / seccomp)? Plain mariadb image or any modifications to it? And /tmp refers to the container (but may also refer to the host if you've mounted something on the host to /tmp inside the container).

Comment: I edited trying to answer your questions.

Comment: Could you also attach the docker-compoe.yml file? It would greatly help understanding the problem.

Comment: @YaronIdan Updated my question :)

Comment: When you were seeing the error, did it say "starting container" instead of "recreating container"? What might have happened is that the old container had exited with a bad state, but was being started each time you ran `up`. When you made a change to the compose file it recreated the container, which cleared out the bad state.

Comment: @dnephin I retried stopping and running the containers (all in the dockerfile as well as `db` individually). Renaming the container caused the output to say "recreating" instead of "starting", but neither message changed anything about the problem until I changed the volumes setting.

Answer (score 0):

i met this issue but in different case
i migrated docker data folder to a new folder (mounted in a new disk)
`cp -R /var/lib/docker/ /data/`
and then change `/etc/docker/daemon.json` into

```json
{
  "data-root": "/data/docker"
}
```

i found the real reason is when using `cp -R`, the perm of docker folder was 711(rwx--x--x)
i changed it (only folder) to 755(rwxr-xr-x) and then things go well

strange but works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).